# How to render a remote web page inside Flutter windows device?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm familiar with webview_flutter to display web page inside ios and android devices. But for this project my target device is windows.
I've tried flutter_html but the page has inline '' and the package has problem with it saying "The  element is not implemented in this library" and as a result the page is broken in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help answer your question, sir. Try to make sure that the library that you are using supports the Windows platform.

[image]